# How do I prioritise a thread called with an asynchronous delegate using BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-priority

I'm acquiring camera images and saving them to hard disk in a separate thread. The thread is called an asynchronous delegate using `BeginInvoke`. The thread may be running for up to 15 minutes. From looking at the saved images and the timings it looks like sometimes frames are missed. I'm wondering if this has something to do with Windows assigning priority to other tasks while the thread is running. Is there a way to assign top priority to my `SaveCameraData` thread.

I've spent a fair bit of time googling this but all the information I can find is on using the "Thread" class and its associated Priority member variable. I don't know how you set an equivalent using asynchronous delegates.

My thread that acquires camera images and saves the image data is called thus;

```
SavecameraData.BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

I think there's a chance that after 5 or 10 minutes my thread is not assigned top priority. Note my application isn't really doing anything else while `SavecameraData` thread is running. The GUI is responsive and is being monitored but that's about it. But I'm concerned windows may be doing housekeeping tasks in the background that is taking priority away from my thread.

Comment: You can't adjust the priority of s thread pool thread, and that's what your code is running on. If you want to play games with a thread, it needs to be one you create. In general,  most of the time when you say "maybe I should bump up the priority of the thread this code is running on" the eventual answer is "no. I guess not".  If the work you are doing is important. consider doing things like making a region of your code immune from garbage collection. Thread priority adjustment is probably not the solution you are looking for

Comment: Your question is too broad. Merely setting the thread priority is trivial: the code executing within the thread can just use `Thread.CurrentThread` to get the current thread, and then change the priority. Contrary to @Fly's statement, it's not true that you _can't_ change the priority of a thread pool thread, but it is true that it's _unwise_ to do so. Those threads are shared and ephemeral. If you want a different priority, you should just create a new thread. Which frankly, for something that runs 15 minutes, is a better idea anyway.

Comment: All that said, it is doubtful you should be messing with thread priority in a thread that's writing to the disk. It seems most likely to me that if you're missing threads, it's because you're wasting time in the thread that's supposed to be doing camera I/O, doing disk I/O instead. Raising priority is almost never the right answer. That's for low-level I/O drivers. User code should response to I/O events as quickly as possible, push long-running, computationally or lengthy I/O operations to some below-normal priority thread that won't interfere with the time-sensitive stuff.

Comment: @PeterDuniho nails it. If avoiding any read-losses/underruns is critical, then the secret to getting this to work is with (thread-safe) queues. You should have a very lightweight reading function on its own (possibly high-prio) thread that pushes all relevant reads into a queue to be processed by a different thread that dequeues the messages from the queue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll create a new thread for this task.

Comment: @Doug You might benefit from looking at [TPL DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library), which provides a high-level abstraction that can ease the development of processing pipelines where producers and consumers move at different rates.